# Google OAuth getting new access token with refresh token

Tags: node.js, post, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to get my `refresh_token` to generate a new `access_token`. I'm using the request module to make the request, but It's returning an error saying something along the lines of "Could not find page".

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function(callback){
    console.log('here');
    request('https://googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?client_id=NotID&client_secret=Not_Secret&refresh_token=NotRefresh&grant_type=refresh_token', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(response)
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
request.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
  form: {
    grant_type:'refresh_token',
    refresh_token:'..',
    client_id:'..',
    client_secret:'..'
  }
}, function (err, res, body) {})
```

Comment: According to the [OAuth 2.0 docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) the correct URL should be `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`

Comment: They probably both work, you can test the above URL.

Comment: it works on me, update url `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`

Answer (score 1):

This works..

```
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const getAccessToken = async refreshToken => {
  try {
    const accessTokenObj = await axios.post(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
      querystring.stringify({
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        client_id: keys.googleClientID,
        client_secret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
      })
    );
    return accessTokenObj.data.access_token;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```